# how to implement concatenate mysql queries in zend framework Model

Tags: zend-framework

Hi i am new in zend framework.

I want to know that it is possible to use concatinate queries in zend model.
example like this we do in core php

```
$abc ="SELECT * FROM emp"
if ($_post ['a'] != '')    
{
    $abc =$abc ." WHERE code=$_post ['a']";   
}   

if ($_post ['b'] != '') 
{
    $abc =$abc ." WHERE name=$_post ['b']"; 
}
$abc.=" ORDER BY datetime;";
```

If possible I want to implement above code in Zend model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do such in zend. Here is the dummy idea for you.

First create the object of the model of `emp` table.

```
$emp = new Application_Model_Emp();

$select = $emp->select();
```

In model `$_POST` is not working so you need to pass the arguments from the controller. Here I am using that as variable.

```
if($a != '') {
  $select->where("code = ?", $a);
} 
if($b != '') {
  $select->where("name = ?", $b);
}

$select->order("datetime");

$rows = $emp->fetchAll($select);
```